# Ubuntu 22.04.1 wake up immediatly after suspend

Tags: plasma

My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Plasma desktop. Every time I click suspend/sleep button, the system goes to sleep and then wake up immediately. I could not find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my issue by installing nvidia driver `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`